# how to make android activity to fit in all size of mobile display's?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have aligned it perfectly in the android studio but when I'm running it, it goes out of order, I have tried in a smartphone as well as in emulator but the result is same.is there any way I can make it display in mobile the same the way I see in the android studio?

[image: click here to see the image]
 The pic that I have uploaded shows that in android studio the display looks perfectly fine but after running its position changes.

this is the xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/wm"
tools:context="sanal.gmail.android.PetCare.doctorassignment">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView9"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/petownerde" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView11"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout6"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/pet" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText10"
    android:layout_width="213dp"
    android:layout_height="142dp"


    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="472dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:hint="Type your message here"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="10"
    android:maxLength="160"
    android:maxLines="5"
    android:minLines="6"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:singleLine="false"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.036"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="99dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="162dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="161dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="162dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="161dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button1"
    android:onClick="sendmessage"
    android:text="SEND"
    android:textColor="#F6F6F6"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText10" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="168dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView11"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.049">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="84dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView21"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Pet name :"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView22"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Breed :"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView23"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Colour :"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView24"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Age :"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView25"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Gender :"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView13"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pet name"
            android:textColor="#F6F6F6"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView14"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="breed"
            android:textColor="#F6F6F6"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView15"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="colour"
            android:textColor="#F6F6F6"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView16"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="age"
            android:textColor="#F6F6F6"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView17"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="gender"
            android:textColor="#F6F6F6"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="136dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView11"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView9">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="79dp"
        android:layout_height="126dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView18"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Name :"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Email :"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Contact : "
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Address : "
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="name"
            android:textColor="#F6F6F6"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="email "
            android:textColor="#F6F6F6"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="phone number"
            android:textColor="#F6F6F6"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="address"
            android:textColor="#F6F6F6"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

`

Comment: Use weights vertically or use scrolling container

Comment: Use `Scrollview` and avoid using `absolute` values

Comment: Add this to value-21 style.xml:
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these two links You will get your answer. Its a time consuming approach but definitely you will learn a lot from these links.

1. http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html
2. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Making fully responsive your android application to all screen sizes is not a very tough job but it requires good knowledge and experience of layouts and there XML properties.

Answer (score 0):

use `RelativeLayout` instead of `constraintLayout`

and give the perfectly position of your views they cant change view your layout

use property of `RelativeLayout` -> `below` , `above` , `toLeftOf` , `toRightOf`

and set your other component

and also `height` and `width` all component not fixed given..

your requirement fixed size then given fixed otherwise use `match_parent` and `wrap_content`

one important things for your layout either you can use `scrollview` coz your `edittext` and `button` are mess ... OR your component size given small then not mess your layout

also you can fixed size or density used then use Dependency SDP and SSP

Answer (score -1):

For android there are several ways to make it Compatible with all the devices.
You can use the ConstraintLayout for more responsive activity instead of LinearLayout.
Apart from that use more flexible and adaptive layout like "match_parent", "wrap_content" instead of hard coded values.
For example -

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:margin_top="5sp"
```

And so on. I hope this will solve your problem.

For more info related to this you can check [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes)